# When using powershell, I cannot configure a Data Collector from my XML template using SetXML method

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

Here the snippet:

```
Write-host "Implementing new data collector set on $Server"
$DataCollectorSet = new-Object -COM Pla.DataCollectorSet
$DataCollectorSet.SetXML($xml)
```

`$xml` is a variable that is populated using the get-content cmdlet.

If I output the `$xml` variable, using `write-host cmdlet`, it displays as I would expect.

It seems that the issue is with the `SetXML` method.

This is what outputs when I run this snippet of the code:

```
**"Exception calling "SetXml" with "1" argument(s): "XML document must have a top level element.**

+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation"
```

---

I looked at XML documentation online and I am convinced that the XML DOES have a top level element.

It should be noted that I did not author the XML document; it was the output of the "Save Template as XML" feature of the Windows Performance monitor.

The end goal is to be able to automate the creation of data collectors over a huge set of servers with a particular profile (processor monitoring, memory monitoring etc.) that was created on my test server.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the `SetXML` method takes a `BSTR` as parameter as discribed in [IDataCollectorSet::SetXml method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The first thing you can test is to try to convert your XML `String` to a `BSTR`:

```
$bstrXml = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::StringToBSTR($xml)
$DataCollectorSet.SetXML($bstrXml)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that. 

I have been using Logman as a workaround for the time being.